How to run own app in Teams via service account for this app
I created the app in PowerApps. This app use the SharePoint and PowerAutomate. In PowerAutomate the Flow use the action "Create item". I can test this app via my account. I pulished this app for my organization and gave them permission to run the app but they need permissions to view and edit the lists in SharePoint's Site.
For security reasons, I don't want to give them viewing and editing rights. But the app requires it, because flow runs use their account. As far as I understand, in SharePoint you can't restrict such rights so that there is only writing, but not reading. Is it possible to somehow make it so that Flow is launched only from a service account, regardless of who exactly launched this application through Teams?

ofcourse. register a new user for the sevrice account and use it to connect with sharepoint and PA. you may need to add necessary licenses. once done, it will work without having to give users the direct access.

To run your app in Teams via a service account, you can utilize a service principal in Power Automate. A service principal is a non-human security identity that can own and manage resources, including running flows.
